# Float environment like figure leaves a empty space in the document

Tags: floats

The image goes at the end of the document because of the float, and its completely fine with me, but it leaves a blank space within the text blocks. How to get rid of it? Please help.
For below code the output is-

```
[Some text].


[Some more text] 


[Some text].
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{secondaryif.png}
    \caption[details of the image. Image source: \href{url}{http://wikipedia.org/wiki/index.php/Image:myimage.png}}
    \label{fig:secondaryif}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
[Some more text]
```

Comment: The `center` environment causes this, and is actually useless anyway, Remove it.

Comment: See [LyX is leaving a big gap between paragraphs in the place where float (figure) should be](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195428) for some discussion on a similar case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LyX is leaving a big gap between paragraphs in the place where float (figure) should be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195333/lyx-is-leaving-a-big-gap-between-paragraphs-in-the-place-where-float-figure-sh)